# Will long polling block a web dyno on cedar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

There is an article in the Heroku devcenter, which explains that long polling is supported on the cedar stack: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

Does that mean the web dyno is blocked for other requests, while the long polling HTTP connection is open?